# Configure of CGAL

Tags: cgal

I've installed cgal-4.13 on my computer(win 8.1, vs 2017) following the instruction (https://www.cgal.org/download/windows.html). But when I try to use cmake to build the example, it always give me the error:

CMake Error at D:/dev/CGAL-4.13-beta1/CGALConfig.cmake:6 (include):
  include could not find load file:

D:/dev/CGAL-4.13-beta1/lib/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake

and could not go on configuring. I searched a lot but still could not find the answer. Could someone please tell me what should I do? Thank you!

Comment: It reminds me of a bug of 4.12 that I though was solved. I'll check but in the mean time, [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/CGAL-4.13-beta1/Installation/CGALConfig.cmake) is the missing file.

Comment: Wrong link, it should be [this one](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/CGAL/cgal/releases/CGAL-4.13-beta1/Installation/lib/cmake/CGAL/CGALConfig.cmake)

Answer (score 0):

There was indeed an issue in the Windows installer for CGAL-4.13-beta1. That is why I have published CGAL-4.13-beta2. Could you give it a try, and then confirm the bug is solved?